# *ngIf block form validation

Tags: angular, conditional-statements

Hello I have been blocked for several days on this problem

I explain to you I have an input or I apply a message according to some condition however I have another condition that says if it is a multiline text used a textarea if it is an inline use an input

When I set my condition *ngIf = "! multiline" in my input I have a problem I have the error message:

Can not read property 'errors' of undefinied

I have applied something, I have encapsulate in a div my input including my condition and I thus, add myModel && myModel.error so that the object is initialized

nothing works

if anyone has a solution I'm interested

this is my code :

```js
import {
  ChangeDetectionStrategy,
  ChangeDetectorRef,
  Component,
  ElementRef,
  forwardRef,
  Input,
  OnInit,
  ViewChild
} from '@angular/core'
import {
  ControlValueAccessor,
  NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR
} from '@angular/forms'
@Component({
  selector: 'mae-input',
  templateUrl: './input.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => InputComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ],
  host: {
    class: 'input-form'
  }
})
export class InputComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {

  @Input() theme: string = 'material' // 'material' or 'block' or 'inline'
  @Input() minlength: number
  @Input() maxlength: number
  @Input() min: number
  @Input() max: number
  @Input() pattern: string
  // tslint:disable-next-line:no-reserved-keywords
  @Input() type: string
  @Input() autocomplete: string
  @Input() required
  @Input() disabled
  @Input() readonly
  @Input() multiline: boolean
  @Input() withCharCount: boolean
  @Input() label: string
  @Input() name: string
  @Input() placeholder: string
  @Input() help: string
  @Input() hint: string
  @Input() bg: string
  @Input() color: string
  @Input() borderColor: string
  @Input() labelColor: string
  @Input() myModel: any

  ValidationHints = {

    required: ' Please fill out this field.',
    minlength: ' Field must be at least 3 characters long.',
    maxlength: ' Field cannot be more than 24 characters long.',
    pattern: ' Please match the requested format.'
  }
  focus: boolean = false

  @ViewChild('inputField')

  private _inputField: ElementRef

  @ViewChild('inputFieldMultiline')

  private _inputFieldMultiline: ElementRef

  private _model: string

  constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {
  }

  // tslint:disable-next-line:no-empty
  onChange: any = () => {
  }

  // tslint:disable-next-line:no-empty
  onTouched: any = () => {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.required = this.required !== undefined && this.required !== false
    this.disabled = this.disabled !== undefined && this.disabled !== false
    this.readonly = this.readonly !== undefined && this.readonly !== false
    this.myModel = ''
  }

  get model() {
    return this._model
  }

  set model(val: string) {
    if (val === this._model) {
      return
    }
    this._model = val
    this.onChange(val)
  }

  writeValue(value: any) {
    this._model = value
    this.cd.markForCheck()
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChange = fn
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouched = fn
  }

  onFocus() {
    if (this.readonly || this.disabled) {
      return
    }
    this.focus = true
  }

  onBlur() {
    if (this.readonly || this.disabled) {
      return
    }
    this.focus = false
    this.onTouched()
  }

  _focusInputField() {
    if(!this.readonly && !this.disabled) {
      if (this.multiline) {
        this._inputFieldMultiline.nativeElement.focus()
      } else {
        this._inputField.nativeElement.focus()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
 <div *ngIf="!multiline">
      <input
        #inputField
        class="input-container__input"
        *ngIf="!multiline"
        (focus)="onFocus()"
        (blur)="onBlur()"
        placeholder="{{placeholder}}"
        name="{{name}}"
        type="{{type || 'text'}}"
        pattern="{{pattern}}"
        minlength="{{minlength}}"
        maxlength="{{maxlength}}"
        min="{{min}}"
        max="{{max}}"
        [required]="required"
        autocomplete="{{autocomplete}}"
        [disabled]="disabled"
        [readonly]="readonly"
        [(ngModel)]="model"
        #myModel="ngModel"
      />
    </div>
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="inputContent"></ng-container>

    <div *ngIf="multiline" class="input-container__multiline">
      <div class="input-container__input input-container__multiline__place-holder">{{model}}</div>
      <textarea
        #inputFieldMultiline
        class="input-container__input input-container__multiline__input"
        [(ngModel)]="model"
        (focus)="onFocus()"
        (blur)="onBlur()"
        placeholder="{{placeholder}}"
        name="{{name}}"
        minlength="{{minlength}}"
        maxlength="{{maxlength}}"
        [required]="required"
        [disabled]="disabled"
        [readonly]="readonly"
        #myModel="ngModel"
      ></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="inputContent"></ng-container>
  {{hint}}
</div>

<ng-template #inputContent>
  <div class="input-container__hints" *ngIf="this.theme !== 'inline'">
    <div class="input-container__hints--left">
      <div *ngIf="myModel && myModel.errors && myModel.touched" class="alert-error">
        <div [hidden]="!myModel.errors.required">
          <i class="mi mi-warning"></i>
          {{ValidationHints.required}}
        </div>
        <div [hidden]="!myModel.errors.minlength">
          <i class="mi mi-warning"></i>
          {{ValidationHints.minlength}}
        </div>
        <div [hidden]="!myModel.errors.maxlength">
          <i class="mi mi-warning"></i>
          {{ValidationHints.maxlength}}
        </div>
        <div [hidden]="!myModel.errors.pattern">
          <i class="mi mi-warning"></i>
          {{ValidationHints.pattern}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="input-container__hints--right" *ngIf="withCharCount">
      {{(model?.length || 0) + (maxlength ? ('/' + maxlength) : '')}}
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Have you tried using the lifecycle hook `ngOnChanges()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Notice here that you have deifned `multiline` as `@Input()` which means you are passing the `multiline` into `InputComponent` from another component.

Use the lifecycle hook `OnChanges` to detect the changes whenever the value of `multiline` is injected or updated from the parent component. Modify your code like this -

Add this import statement :

```
import {OnChanges, SimpleChanges} from '@angular/core';
```

Add this lines to `InputComponent`:

```
export class InputComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccesso, OnChanges {

 // other code goes here

 public multiline: boolean = false;   <--- define an initial value

 ngOnChanges(changes:SimpleChanges){
    if('multiline' in changes){       <---- detect changes and update
      this.multiline = changes['multiline'].currentValue;
   }
 }
}
```

If you are geting similar errors for other properties defined with `@Input()` consider implementing the above pattern for them as well.

Hope it helps.